# How does a vector<vector<int>> allocates memory for the inner vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector, allocation

I get how vectors works in general as far as memory allocation is concerned, but what happens when you use a vector to store a vector of some simple type.

The simple solution is to always use pointers for the inner vectors, but then what's the difference between declaring something like "`vector<vector<int>> a`" to declaring something like "`vector<vector<int>*> b`"?

In the case where it's actually a contiguous block of memory for the inner vectors what happens when a reallocation breaks the boundaries of memory that could be used? Is everything copied to a new block? That seems unlikely because it's so expensive, but then it goes back to the question in the second paragraph.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: A vector is only 16 bytes long (the size, capacity, and a pointer to the data) so allocating space for a vector is the same as making space for any other item.

Comment: each vector has a pointer to its own block of contiguous memory

Comment: There are no special rules for elements of types `vector<something>`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt except for `vector<bool>` !

Comment: @OP -- How about a `std::vector<std::list<int>>`?  Or `std::vector<std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>>>`?  Except for `std::vector<bool>`, as long as the `T` in `std::vector<T>` [meets the requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of what can be placed in a vector, then that's all that matters.  It isn't as if the internal vector code has a gigantic switch statement, trying to figure out the types being used and does things differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `vector<vector<int>>` uses `std::allocator` for both the outer and inner vectors. These are all independent allocations.

`std::vector` supports custom allocators, and in particular it supports `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor` to share an allocator across nesting levels. So you could write an allocator to try to keep things in contiguous memory. But as you already noted, there are limits to what you can achieve. For every allocator, there's always an allocation pattern that will fragment allocations.

Answer (score 0):

A `vector<vector<T>>` is not a special case of `std::vector`. There is no special allocation code that gets used when you use a `vector<vector<T>>`. Every `vector<T>` that you put into this `vector<vector<T>>` manages its allocations by itself. The surrounding vector only manages the allocation that contains each `vector<int>` itself (but not the allocations that *they* manage).

Concerning your second question, the difference between a `vector<vector<T>>` and a `vector<vector<T>*>` (I assume this is the kind of type you meant when you used the asterisk), is that the second one is a vector of *pointers* to vector of `T`, while the first one is a vector of vectors of `T`.

And just to emphasize, the memory managed by the inner vectors do not form one giant contiguous memory block.

It's worth pointing out though that `std::vector` *does* have one special case for a particular type: `std::vector<bool>`. Standard library implementations are encouraged by the standard to write it in such a way that when you use `std::vector<bool>`, it only stores 1 bit for each `bool`, instead of a full byte. This can reduce memory usage, at the cost of a tiny bit of runtime efficiency, since you now need extra instructions to extract individual bits whenever you access elements of that vector. `vector<bool>` is also sometimes annoying in template metaprogramming, since its methods are actually slightly different from the normal `std::vector`. I hope this gave some insight.